# angular how to set attribute inside directive/template dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

just started playing with Angular. I have several modal. same structure with header and footer. And the main part is a tree. I have data for three different tree.

I am using [angular ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). and [abn tree](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Select your option</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <abn-tree tree-data="{{treeData}}"                          
                      icon-leaf="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"
                      on-select="treeClickHandler(branch)"
                      expand-level="1"
                      initial-selection="Select Subject">
            </abn-tree>        
        </div>            
    </script>
```

in my html. i have multiple places where i use this

```
<my-modal data-treeDataSource="tree1"></my-modal>
<my-modal data-treeDataSource="tree2"></my-modal>
<my-modal data-treeDataSource="tree3"></my-modal>
```

in my app.js

```
app = angular.module('myApp', deps).directive('myModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',      
    templateUrl: 'my-template.html'
  };
});;

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {


    //set treeData for the first modal and second modal, etc.  
    Sscope.tree1 = tree1Data1;
    Sscope.tree2 = tree1Data2;
    Sscope.tree3 = tree1Data3;



});
```

In my controller, i just set the tree data. I need three modal with different tree data source. I can write three different template with different data attribute.  My questions are

1. What is the best way to differentiate different directives. by data or id or antything else
2. What is the best way to set "tree-data" in my model. I dont have actual data at the time of directive binding. I have the data inside the controller.

Appreciate your time tor read the question.

Comment: 1. Probably by id. It has to be unique anyway. 2. You might need a $watch in your directive to "do something" when the data changes.

Comment: $watch is to check if state is changed. Here i m binding data. Something related to scope in the directive but i cant figure it out right now... thanks for your comment

Comment: Hm, perhaps you should create an isolate scope for the directive and bind the attribute through?